# What is the number of $4$ tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ whereas $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z^+}$ satisfying the following $3$ equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a^3=b^2$

$c^3=d^2$

$c-a=64$

I tried this way :

$c-a=64$

$\Rightarrow \frac{d^2}{c^2}-\frac{b^2}{a^2}=(\pm 8)^2$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{d}{c})^2-(\frac{b}{a})^2=(\pm 8)^2$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{d}{c}-\frac{b}{a}) (\frac{d}{c}+\frac{b}{a})=(\pm 8)^2 $

$\Rightarrow\frac{d}{c}-\frac{b}{a}=\pm 8 $    & $\frac{d}{c}+\frac{b}{a}=\pm 8$

So, now I can get $4$ equations each having $4$ variables but how can I know the number of solutions without actually solving those?Is there any way or I have to solve!!

Comment: How did you perform the step starting with 'Then,'? That seems illegitimate.

Comment: $a=x^2,b=x^3,c=y^2,d=y^3$ and you have $y^2-x^2=64$

Comment: Note that it suffices to find $a$ and $c$ such that they are square.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491001/242)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Big Hint:** For integers,$a,b$, having $a^3=b^2$ [means that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3065795/242) $a$ is a perfect square and $b$ is a perfect cube. Likewise for $c$ and $d.$ Then if $a=a_0^2,$ you get $b=a_0^3,$ and $c=c_0^2,d=c_0^3.$ Now you need:

$$c-a=(c_0-a_0)(c_0+a_0)=64.$$

There are only so many ways to factor $64,$ and for each you can solve for $c_0$ and $a_0$ and get a solution $(a,b,c,d)=(a_0^2,a_0^3,c_0^2,c_0^3)$ when $a_0,c_0$ are both positive integers.

---

Note that my $c_0=\frac{d}{c}$ and $a_0=\frac{b}{a}$ from your beginnings.

You are assuming the factorization of $64$ is $(\pm 8)(\pm 8).$ But there are other factorizations of $64,$ and just because $UV=8\cdot 8$ doesn't mean that $U=\pm 8,V=\pm 8.$ Indeed, given that $U=c_0-a_0\neq c_0+a_0=V,$ you probably want other factorizations. When $U=V$ here, you get $a_0=0$ and hence $a=0,$ which violates the condition that $a$ is positive.

Comment: The two factors have to have the same parity for $a_0,c_0$ to be integers.

Comment: Yeah, decided to skip over that, but yes, you still need $a_0,c_0$ positive integers.

Comment: Yeah!! I got it now!!there's some silly mistakes i did!! @ThomasAndrews